# Google Chrome Black Screen... of death?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, macos-sierra

I am randomly getting these black squares, and the only way to get rid of them and see a webpage is to restart the browser. What could possibly be causing the issue?

P.S. I am using the latest Google Chrome (Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)) on macOS Sierra 10.12.

[image: Black Screen of Death]

Comment: Good that I'm not alone. Also getting on ver 53.0.2785.143. This happens quite randomly.

Comment: just curious .. have you tried disabling hardware acceleration under advanced settings ?

Comment: This is off topic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even though this an off topic question,

Try **disabling hardware acceleration** under **advanced settings**

As @giacatho below summarised here are the steps:

1. Visit browser settings (chrome://settings/)
2. Click "Show advanced settings..."
3. Uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available"

Comment: More details:
1. Visit browser settings (chrome://settings/)
2. Click "Show advanced settings..."
3. Uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available"